# Cannot cast java.util.Collections$EmptySet to java.util.HashSet

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm using Vaadin14 and Java 1.8. I want to implement a multi-select combobox, which is why I am using the following Vaadin addon: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/multiselect-combo-box/api/org/vaadin/gatanaso/MultiselectComboBox.html

Instantiating and using the combobox works great, but I'm getting the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.Collections$EmptySet to java.util.HashSet
```

when trying to "save" an object without any items selected in the combobox. If I have at least one item  selected, it works fine, but as soon as the selection is empty and I try to save the object ("AnotherClass"), i receive the error.

```
// creating a combobox 
private MultiselectComboBox<MyClass> multiselectComboBox;
multiselectComboBox= new MultiselectComboBox<>();   

// setting items to choose from
final MyClassDataProvider dataProvider = new MyClassDataProvider();
List<MyClass> allAvailableOptions = new ArrayList<>(dataProvider.getItems());
multiselectComboBox.setItems(allAvailableOptions);
multiselectComboBox.setItemLabelGenerator(MyClass::getName); // display name only

// binding the combobox to a field of AnotherClass
binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(AnotherClass.class);
binder.forField(multiselectComboBox)
            .bind("myHashSet");

// save-button
save = new Button("Save");
save.addClickListener(event -> {
    if (currentObject!= null
         && binder.writeBeanIfValid(currentObject)) { // error in this line
         viewLogic.saveRisk(currentObject);
    }
    });
```

The HashSet is an attribute in the following class:

```
public class AnotherClass  implements Serializable {

     @NotNull
     private int id = -1;

     private HashSet<MyClass> myHashSet= new HashSet<MyClass>();

}
```

When I create instances of AnotherClass I always instantiate them not with null but with an empty HashSet for the attribute myHashSet.

How can I fix the error above?

Comment: Liskov substitution principle: Refer to it as `Set<MyClass> myHashSet` instead. This allows you to refer to both types, both of which are serializable.

Comment: @Rogue Please don't write answers in comments

Comment: I exchanged Set for HashSet, but now I get an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch Error instead in the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the hint @Rogue gave me in the comments, I tried it with Set<> first, but what finally did the trick was going another level of abstraction upwards and using Collection<> instead of HashSet<> in the class definition ([Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)).

```
public class AnotherClass  implements Serializable {

     @NotNull
     private int id = -1;

     private Collection<MyClass> myHashSet= new HashSet<MyClass>();

}
```